# How can I find specific but obscure elements in Selenium, without a parser like Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to try and find a group of specific elements in a web page that look like this:

```
<br>Time remaining: <span style='color:red;font-weight:bold' > 4 mins, 40 secs</span>
<br>Time remaining: <span style='color:red;font-weight:bold' > 12 mins</span>
<br>Time remaining: <span  > 5 hrs, 39 mins</span>
```

There are usually around 10 to 20 of these and before I realized that some weren't red, I just used this:

```
timeleft = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[style='color:red;font-weight:bold']")
```

The text of the element can vary between "mins, secs" , "mins" , "secs" , "hrs , mins" etc. I am trying to find a way to get those elements without the "style" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, unless the time words show up in other spans on the page that you don't want included...

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//span[contains(text(), 'secs') or contains(text(), 'mins') or contains(text(), 'hrs')]")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew about xpath, just not "contains" and "or". Those time words don't show up anywhere else so it should be good. By the way, is having a new line for something long or with parenthesis a good practice? I've seen it a few times but I didn't know

Comment: If you follow PEP8 standards all lines must wrap before 80 characters.  I didn't here, but that's usually why you see it.